# How to download and install IPX on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-protocols

From where I can download IPX for windows 7 and how to install it?
Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: IPX? As in the Novell networking protocol? If so, why?

Comment: I'm trying to get Network Play on Command and Conquer Red Alert 2 working so I need the IPX protocol if Novell can provide that can you please send me the download link? Thanks again

Comment: Have you tried downloading the Netware client?  Registration is required but it's a free download.  (Admittedly, old data, I haven't touched it in over 2 years now.)

Answer (score 6):

You can try this IPX over UDP software.

http://www.solemnwarning.net/ipxwrapper/

Let us know how it turns out.

Comment: Brilliant! It works! Just make sure you read the `readme.txt` from top to bottom. And it's even open-source. Solemn is a genius.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's official answer is to ask Novell as it is a Novell protocol. Novell's official answer is that it is a Microsoft operating system, ask Microsoft. (Recent versions of Novell Client do not support IPX)

For gaming [ipx wrapper](http://www.solemnwarning.net/ipxwrapper/) appears to be the best bet, but is not compatible with ipx at the wire level. There are advantages as this allows you to play with people on other networks without doing ipx routing. The disadvantages are that if you have some computers that talk ipx, you still need the wrapper, and it is not available for os/2, netware or linux (or anything else besides windows, although source code is available).

For use with industrial equipment like cnc setups there are no good answers. Less bad ones are things like virtual machines, ftp servers and ask the vendor (which is occasionally useful).

You may be able to get xp's drivers to work on newer operating systems, but getting it to work with 64bit operating systems does not appear to work and 32bit operating systems are difficult at best.

You are in about the same boat for netbeui, but there is some support for dlc from microsoft but they use ip and a gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/518344-windows-7-ipx.html) which may work, basically hack IPX into Windows 7 using XP's IPX drivers.